# Using DOMDOcument in PHP to parse XML and return an array of tree structure

Tags: php, domdocument

I am very sorry if my question doesn't make sense as this is my first question, however i've been going through the questions posted for a while now.

right i have a XML structure of

```
<category>
  <id>123456</id>
  <name>Sales</name>
<categories>
  <category>
    <id>2345</id>
    <name>UK House prices</name>
  </category>
  <category>
    <id>3456</id>
    <name>Property Market Surveys</name>
  </category>
</categories>
```

I'd want a function to parse through the above xml and generate an array idealy to look something like this

```
array(
  "123456" => 
  array(
    "id" => "2345",
    "name" => "UK House prces",
  ),
  array(
    "id" => "3456",
    "name" => "Property Market Surveys",
  )
);
```

i must then be able to extract data of the array and insert it into a table with parent child relation.

Please let me know if you need more info to make this question complete.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need it? If you want to access the XML tree in a simple fashion (similar to arrays, except array notation is only used when there are siblings with the same element name, otherwise the property notation is used), you can use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml).

Comment: hey there, sorry for the late reply....but yeah you're right i did manage to use simplexml and kinda created a function similar to the one shown below by Chief17.

I've managed to convert the xml into an array the way i wanted....i shall try and use that array to insert the data into the table and that will have a parent child relation within the same table.

let me see how that goes, anyway thanks very much for your time and efforts...you guys are amazing....

Answer (score 3):

This function seems to work, if you google [php xml to array](http://google.co.uk/search?q=php+xml+to+array) you get loads of good relevant results back.
Here is a good starting point: (sourced from http://snipplr.com/view/17886/xml-to-array/)

Just specify the XML as the parameter and it returns an array:

```
function xml2array($xml,$recursive = false) {

 if (!$recursive ) { $array = simplexml_load_string ($xml); }
 else { $array = $xml ; }

 $newArray = array();
 $array = $array ;

 foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
     $value = (array) $value;

     if (isset($value[0])) { $newArray[$key] = trim($value[0]); }
     else { $newArray[$key][] = XML2Array($value,true) ; }
 }

 return $newArray;
}
```

Comment: hello thanks very much for your time, i've managed to create a function similar to this but the way i wanted it. i've got what i wanted so far....lets see how the rest of it goes. cheers mate.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the last solution with a better indexing of nodes ( by name ) and reducing the number of parameters :

```
function xml2Array( $xml )
{
    $xml = ( array )( is_string( $xml ) ? simplexml_load_string( $xml ) : $xml ) ;

    $parse = array() ;
    foreach( $xml as $key => $value )
    {
        $parse[$key] = is_string( $value ) 
            ? trim( $value ) 
            : $this->xml2Array( $value )
        ;
    }

    return $parse ;
}
```